# Php code fails to give corrent result most likely logic error

Tags: php, arrays, logic, collision-detection

I have been racking my brain on this problem for the last few days and for the life of me can seem to find the issue code. Essentially this code generates a random amount of objects with an x and y coord and a radius, then the code check to see whether the new object collides with any other object, if it dosen't then it will add it to a master array which is then returned the the calling function. My issue is that when i load the page all the objects are there but some still collide with each other and i can't figure out why. Can anyone see the issue?

```
public function Generate($chunkX, $chunkY) {
    if (!(isset($this->ChunkX) && isset($this->ChunkY) )) {
        $this->ChunkX = $chunkX;
        $this->ChunkY = $chunkY;
    }
    $counter = 0;
    $this->ObjectLocations = array();
    $totalAstroids = $this->GetAstroidNo();


    while ($counter < $totalAstroids) {
        $tempObjectLocations = array();
        //X and Y Chunk Coordinates
        $tempObjectLocations['chunkX'] = $chunkX;
        $tempObjectLocations['chunkY'] = $chunkY;
        //X and Y coordinates for the object.
        $tempObjectLocations['coordX'] = rand(4, 60);
        $tempObjectLocations['coordY'] = rand(4, 60);
        $tempObjectLocations['radius'] = rand(4, 12);
        //Checks if objects already exist in array
        if (count($this->ObjectLocations) > 0) {

            //if the object does not collide with any other object 
            //the location will be added into the database
            if ($this->isColliding($tempObjectLocations) == false) {
                array_push($this->ObjectLocations, $tempObjectLocations);
                $counter += 1;
            }
            // if object is the first created insert into table.
        } else {
            array_push($this->ObjectLocations, $tempObjectLocations);
            $counter += 1;
        }
    }

    return $this->ObjectLocations;
}
public function isColliding($obj1) {
    //Checks if object conflicts with nearby objects
    $a = count($this->ObjectLocations);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $a; $i++) {
        $obj2 = $this->ObjectLocations[$i];

        //Calculates the distance between two points
        $distance = sqrt(($obj1['coordX'] - $obj2['coordX']) ^ 2 + ($obj1['coordY'] - $obj2['coordY']) ^ 2);

        //Checks if the distance between the two objects is 
        //more than the radius of both objects added together
        if ($distance < ($obj1['radius'] + $obj2['radius'] )) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Json result

```
parseResponse([
{
    "chunkX": "1",
    "chunkY": "1",
    "coordX": 54,
    "coordY": 17,
    "radius": 8
},
{
    "chunkX": "1",
    "chunkY": "1",
    "coordX": 41,
    "coordY": 57,
    "radius": 12
},
{
    "chunkX": "1",
    "chunkY": "1",
    "coordX": 42,
    "coordY": 36,
    "radius": 8
},
{
    "chunkX": "1",
    "chunkY": "1",
    "coordX": 40,
    "coordY": 58,
    "radius": 8
},
{
    "chunkX": "1",
    "chunkY": "1",
    "coordX": 25,
    "coordY": 58,
    "radius": 12
},
{
    "chunkX": "1",
    "chunkY": "1",
    "coordX": 57,
    "coordY": 8,
    "radius": 10
},
{
    "chunkX": "1",
    "chunkY": "1",
    "coordX": 46,
    "coordY": 17,
    "radius": 11
},
{
    "chunkX": "1",
    "chunkY": "1",
    "coordX": 42,
    "coordY": 29,
    "radius": 8
},
{
    "chunkX": "1",
    "chunkY": "1",
    "coordX": 18,
    "coordY": 58,
    "radius": 11
},
{
    "chunkX": "1",
    "chunkY": "1",
    "coordX": 59,
    "coordY": 5,
    "radius": 11
},
{
    "chunkX": "1",
    "chunkY": "1",
    "coordX": 15,
    "coordY": 56,
    "radius": 12
}
```

]);

Comment: Can you update your question with a var_dump of the resulting $this->ObjectLocations ?

Comment: Sure ill up date it in a little

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some proposition. In your `isColliding`:

```
public function isColliding($obj1) {
    //Checks if object conflicts with nearby objects
    $a = count($this->ObjectLocations);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $a; $i++) {
        $obj2 = $this->ObjectLocations[$i];

        //Calculates the distance between two points
        $distance = sqrt(($obj1['coordX'] - $obj2['coordX']) ^ 2 + ($obj1['coordY'] - $obj2['coordY']) ^ 2);

        //Checks if the distance between the two objects is 
        //more than the radius of both objects added together
        if ($distance < ($obj1['radius'] + $obj2['radius'] )) { // -> Bad idea !
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have marked bad place. Why ? Because you treat asteroids like a mass point but in fact there are not. If sum of theirs radius will be equal to distance between them they still will collide each other. So this condition should looks like:

```
if ($distance <= ($obj1['radius'] + $obj2['radius'] )) { // -> Should work :)
                return true;
            }
```

Everyone looks but not see. There is some basic mistake (of cours I didn't see this also :) ). In PHP **^** operator is a XOR operator not power operator :)
so correct notation for your script is:

```
public function isColliding($obj1) {
    //Checks if object conflicts with nearby objects
    $a = count($this->ObjectLocations);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $a; $i++) {
        $obj2 = $this->ObjectLocations[$i];

        //Calculates the distance between two points
//correct ^2 to pow function
        $distance = sqrt(pow($obj1['coordX'] - $obj2['coordX'], 2) + pow($obj1['coordY'] - $obj2['coordY'], 2));

        //Checks if the distance between the two objects is 
        //more than the radius of both objects added together
        if ($distance < ($obj1['radius'] + $obj2['radius'] )) { // -> Bad idea !
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: of course comparision should be "<=" not "<". (Of course in my opinion :)) I have overlooked this when edit

Comment: @Soyale nice catch on the ^ operator. I overlooked that completely haha :)

Comment: thanks in all the years ive done php i didnt know that about the ^ symbol, learn something new everyday

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not helpful answer, but ... I think your IF/ELSE statements should lead to two different states?

```
        if ($this->isColliding($tempObjectLocations) == false) {
            array_push($this->ObjectLocations, $tempObjectLocations);
            $counter += 1;
        }
        // if object is the first created insert into table.
    } else {
        array_push($this->ObjectLocations, $tempObjectLocations);
        $counter += 1;
    }
```

As I can see you push it into an array whether it collides or not?

Comment: That case is just preventing a collision check if the array is empty anyway. He could leave it out with the same effect, but it's just an optimization. Edit: but I agree on the fact it can be written better.

Comment: OK, sorry then, but where are you checking if it collides - to not create that object? It seems to me you never stop creating objects in your Generate method. I mean, the array is not empty after first iteration, then on the second one, nothing will stop an object to be created no matter the coordinates

Comment: He's checking that in his isColliding method.

Comment: That's clear, but the method is not used to prevent the array_push, isn't it? Maybe I should stop commenting, feel dumb and non-helpful.

Comment: if(this->isColliding(..) == false) .. in the first line in your code-quote.